How can I make this kind of list 1., 1.1, 1.1.1, ... and 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.1.1, ...?
Code
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,12pt,finnish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} % before hyperref
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{xurl} % after biblatex
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

\section{1. Maarakennuksen virheet}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1.1. Pumppukuoppien puuttuminen
\item 1.1.1. Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    Tahallisuus.
\item 1.1.1.1. Viite todisteluaineistoon
\item 1.1.1.1.1. Kustannusvaikutus
\end{enumerate}

1.2. Koneella liikkuminen rakennuspohjalla
1.2.1. Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    Tahallisuus. Kaivuu pohja rikottu paalutuskoneella.
    pohjan vauriot, pohjan täytöt, solumuovi, suodatinkangas, savisilmät.
1.2.1.1. Viite todisteluaineistoon
1.2.1.1.1. Kustannusvaikutus


\section{2. Alapohjan virheet}
2.1. Ontelolaattojen asennus: saumavalu ja työvaihe
2.1.1. Virheen kuvaus ja vaikutukset
2.1.1.1 Viite todisteluaineistoon
2.1.1.1.1. Kustannusvaikutus


\end{document}

Wanted output where the indendation should be on the left-hand-side
1. Maarakennuksen virheet

1.1. Pumppukuoppien puuttuminen
1.1.1. Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    Tahallisuus!
1.1.1.1. Viite todisteluaineistoon
1.1.1.1.1. Kustannusvaikutus

1.2. Koneella liikkuminen rakennuspohjalla
1.2.1. Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    Tahallisuus. Kaivuu pohja rikottu paalutuskoneella.
    pohjan vauriot, pohjan täytöt, solumuovi, suodatinkangas, savisilmät.
1.2.1.1. Viite todisteluaineistoon
1.2.1.1.1. Kustannusvaikutus

2. Alapohjan virheet
2.1. Ontelolaattojen asennus: saumavalu ja työvaihe
2.1.1. Virheen kuvaus ja vaikutukset
2.1.1.1 Viite todisteluaineistoon
2.1.1.1.1. Kustannusvaikutus

Maybe some new definition would be easiest solution.
Maybe the package would be useful here:
\usepackage{enumitem}

Try Stephen
\begin{mylist}
  \item Maarakennuksen virheet
  \begin{mylist}
    \item Pumppukuoppien puuttuminen
    \begin{mylist}
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
      \begin{mylist}
        \item Viite todisteluaineistoon
        \begin{mylist}
          \item Kustannusvaikutus
        \end{mylist}
      \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
  \end{mylist}

    \begin{mylist}
    \item Koneella liikkuminen rakennuspohjalla
    \begin{mylist}
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
      \begin{mylist}
        \item Viite todisteluaineistoon
        \begin{mylist}
          \item Kustannusvaikutus
        \end{mylist}
      \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}

Output where the sublist does not count.
It should be 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.1.1, 12.1.1.1.

Try on Mico
I get this output in a real environment:

OS: Debian latest

You may achieve the desired indentation by using the left=0pt option while running the various \setlist instructions.

\documentclass[draft,a4paper,12pt,finnish]{article} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} % before hyperref 
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{xurl} % after biblatex
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\usepackage{secdot}

\counterwithin{enumi}{section}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\theenumi.,left=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi\arabic*.,left=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\theenumii\arabic*.,left=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=\theenumiii\arabic*.,left=0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Maarakennuksen virheet}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Pumppukuoppien puuttuminen
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    Tahallisuus.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Viite todisteluaineistoon
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Kustannusvaikutus
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

\item Koneella liikkuminen rakennuspohjalla
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    Tahallisuus. Kaivuu pohja rikottu paalutuskoneella.
    pohjan vauriot, pohjan täytöt, solumuovi, suodatinkangas, savisilmät.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Viite todisteluaineistoon
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Kustannusvaikutus
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\section{Alapohjan virheet}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Ontelolaattojen asennus: saumavalu ja työvaihe
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Virheen kuvaus ja vaikutukset
    \begin{enumerate} 
      \item Viite todisteluaineistoon
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Kustannusvaikutus
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


Addendum to address one of the OP's follow-up comments, viz.,

LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.

Since the code I posted does not throw this type of error, all I can surmise at this point is that the OP's additional (and so far known only to the OP) code does something illegal. By default, the LaTeX enumerate environment can be nested up, and only up to, four levels. Question: Are you trying to somehow generate a 5th or 6th nested enumerate environment? That would definitely throw an error. Do note that this issue is entirely unrelated to the code I posted.
If you do need more than 4 nested levels, I suggest you create a new set of enumerate-like environments, employing some additional capabilities of the enumitem package. The following code assumes you need to up 6 levels.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{6}
\counterwithin{myenumi}{section}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label=\themyenumi.,left=0pt}
\setlist[myenum,2]{label=\themyenumi\arabic*.,  left=0pt}
\setlist[myenum,3]{label=\themyenumii\arabic*., left=0pt}
\setlist[myenum,4]{label=\themyenumiii\arabic*.,left=0pt}
\setlist[myenum,5]{label=\themyenumiv\arabic*., left=0pt}
\setlist[myenum,6]{label=\themyenumv\arabic*.,  left=0pt}

and then type \begin{myenum} and \end{myenum} in the body of the document instead of the usual \begin{enumerate} and \end{enumerate}.

I get this warning `l.190 \item
Kustannusvaikutus
?
! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.`. Why?'

I added what I get in real environment in the body. Some interaction somehow? How to prevent them? For some reason the counting is not working as expected.

@LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - Please see the addendum I posted.

How should this work left=0pt? I cannot get the list be on the left-hand-side?

@LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - If you want the lists and their contents to be typeset fully flush-left, please change all instances of left=0pt to wide=0pt.

Works! Thank you!

This is similar to @Stephen's answer but picking up the current section number for the first level of your lists, and also changing the behaviour of enumerate instead of defining a new list.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\section{Maarakennuksen virheet}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Maarakennuksen virheet
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Pumppukuoppien puuttuminen
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Pumppukuoppien puuttuminen
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Maarakennuksen virheet
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Pumppukuoppien puuttuminen
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Pumppukuoppien puuttuminen
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}



? The image is exactly my output. If you get another output that's your fault and you should ask a follow up question, because the code in this answer does answer your initial question. That's how the site works.

The enumitem package provides an interface called label*=<commands>.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
  \item Maarakennuksen virheet
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
    \item Pumppukuoppien puuttuminen
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[mylist]{label*=\arabic*.}

\begin{mylist}
  \item Maarakennuksen virheet
  \begin{mylist}
    \item Pumppukuoppien puuttuminen
    \begin{mylist}
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
      \begin{mylist}
        \item Viite todisteluaineistoon 
        \begin{mylist}
          \item Kustannusvaikutus    
        \end{mylist}  
      \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
    \item Koneella liikkuminen rakennuspohjalla
    \begin{mylist}
      \item Virheen kuvaus ja tekniset vaikutukset
      \begin{mylist}
        \item Viite todisteluaineistoon 
        \begin{mylist}
          \item Kustannusvaikutus    
        \end{mylist}  
      \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
  \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}
\end{document}



How can you make the list indented to the left?

This is wrong. The second class of items does not enumerate, please see the body soon.

@LéoLéopoldHertz준영 See the updated version.

A solution with paralist. Note that this is limited to four item levels (but it have little sense to have more when items are indented with long labels):

\documentclass[draft,a4paper,12pt,finnish]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pointedenum,alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\setdefaultenum
{\sffamily\bfseries\thesection.1}
{\sffamily\bfseries\thesection.\theenumi.1}
{\sffamily\bfseries\thesection.\theenumi.\theenumii.1}
{\sffamily\bfseries\thesection.\theenumi.\theenumii.\theenumiii.1}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{7}
\section{foo}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item \lipsum[2][1-2]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[3][1-3]
\item \lipsum[4][1-4]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[5][1-4]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[7][1-6]
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[9][1-2]
\end{enumerate}
\section{bar}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[4][1-2]
\item \lipsum[8][1-2]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[6][1-2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

